# Does nginx have dynamic includes?

Tags: nginx

Is there any way to include a config file that gets reloaded on each request (maybe only when is modified)?

Something like:

```
server {
    ...
    dynamic_include $document_root/.nginx;
}
```

This could make people able to reproduce in a efficient way .htaccess found in Apache as it is **opt-in** and wouldn't `stat()` every folder out there...

Comment: Not doing this was a deliberate design decision; nginx is intended for high performance, and reading a configuration on every page load would have a significant impact.

Comment: @MichaelHampton it's still possible with the Lua module (see my answer)

Answer (score 2):

Normal configuration files are read only once (during startup and when requested externaly), but you can use the [HttpLuaModule](http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpLuaModule) to have a piece of **Lua** script to be evaluated at each request. Nginx provides 4 request phases (rewrite, access, content, log) in which Lua scripts can be executed.

Here are some thing you can do with Lua (from manual):

> - Mashup'ing and processing outputs of various nginx upstream outputs    (proxy, drizzle, postgres, redis, memcached, and etc) in Lua,
> - doing arbitrarily complex access control and security checks in Lua before requests actually reach the upstream backends,
> - manipulating response headers in an arbitrary way (by Lua)
> - fetching backend information from external storage backends (like redis, memcached, mysql, postgresql) and use that information to choose which upstream backend to access on-the-fly,
> - coding up arbitrarily complex web applications in a content handler using synchronous but still non-blocking access to the database backends and other storage,
> - doing very complex URL dispatch in Lua at rewrite phase,
> - using Lua to implement advanced caching mechanism for Nginx's subrequests and arbitrary locations.

Comment: But can you use lua to dynamically include an nginx config file?  If so can you give example code?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not aware of any way to do what you're looking for.

I've not come across this in any of my work with nginx, or while researching the nginx documentation or the Internet.

If something like this exists (or is feasible) it may exist as a module (though I was not able to find one that does what you're looking for) http://wiki.nginx.org/Modules

### Here is a suggestion:

Your main config file would ideally look to one folder where all your configs are stored. If you have configs stored in other locations one suggestion would be to make symlinks to these locations so that nginx still things they're all stored in the one spot.

### Some food for thought:

What would be possible, is ... manually (or via script) doing a reload of nginx:

http://wiki.nginx.org/CommandLine

> Configuration reload Start the new worker processes with a new
>   configuration Gracefully shutdown the old worker processes

You could create a bash script that could watch certain folders for for modifications or new files with .conf (or .nginx) and then proceed to reload nginx.

WARNING: I'm not sure that's such a great idea (automatically reloading nginx), at least not in production...as you could have a syntax error, or an otherwise bad config that could cause adverse effects if not properly tested.

Comment: If you reload nginx with a bad config, it just keeps going with its original configuration.

Comment: That's a fine example of something you need to cater for. You have to check to see if the new config has loaded or if nginx is still serving the original. That could be a point of confusion in the senario proposed by the OP.

Comment: @DrewKhoury `nginx -t` will test the config file for errors, upon which you could roll back.

Answer (score -1):

You can use wildcard folder name. For example, if your document root is /path/example.com/.nginx, you can use

```
include /path/*/.nginx
```

But this file will be read once on start/reload, not dynamic.